# Can we get a list of phandles mapped to node names from a DTB or DTBO?

Tags: linux, device-tree

From the [Device Tree Specification v0.3](https://github.com/devicetree-org/devicetree-specification/releases/tag/v0.3), section 2.3.3 of *phandle*, I found the following note -

> Note: Most devicetrees in DTS (Device Tree Source) (see Appendix A) will not contain explicit phandle properties. The DTC (Device Tree Compiler) tool automatically inserts the phandle properties when the DTS is compiled into the binary DTB (Device Tree Binary) format.

My question is that is there a way after compiling the DTS into a DTB format, can we get a list of the assigned *phandle* values mapped with the corresponding node name. And also would it be possible if DTBO is the final output?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas that I have thought (both are basically based on the idea of parsing a specific format and coming up with a table) -

1. Convert the DTB into a FDT and then use the FDT libraries in C to parse through the whole device tree and get the list of *phandle* and node names. But I wanted to know if such a mechanism has already been implemented through the DTC or any other tool.
2. Convert the compiled DTB into DTS by the use of DTC and then parse the DTS (now with the *phandle*) with the help of a script (for eg, python, bash, etc.)

These are just some brainstorm ideas but I would like comments from others regarding this, for eg., if there is such a mechanism has already been implemented through the DTC or any other tool, it might be counter-productive implementing the above ideas.

Comment: Did this go anywhere? For a user-space program parsing a devicetree it would be pretty useful to be able to convert phandles back to paths. And related to this, a way to traverse phandles within the `/proc/device-tree` file system would be helpful too. Is there anything around to help with this?